# DB2 developer community edition hangs at "Starting docker containers..."

Tags: ubuntu, docker, db2

DB2 developer community-edition hangs at "Starting docker containers..."

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 , bare-metal, Xeon E5-2660 cpu. 128GB RAM.

Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72

Using:  ibm-db2-developer_community_edition-1.1.2-x86_64.AppImage

Symptom is recreatable.

The installation hangs at 79% on the step "Starting docker containers..." and it will never complete.

The Output of `docker ps -a` during this time:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES f2ed37f629cc        db2server:v11.1.2fp2_2   "/var/db2_setup/li..."   33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   db2server
```

Looks like the program tries to start 2 containers(db2server*, and dsm*), the second depends on the first, but the second does start because it complains that the first does not exist? Some timing issue? Maybe I misinterpret the log file below.

From the end of the log file ( /home/tang/.config/ibm-db2-developerc/Logs/db2-developerc.log ):

snip...

```
[2017-09-07 12:19:09:0627] [info] Db2server command to execute is:
[2017-09-07 12:19:09:0627] [info] docker run -h db2server_e247e0 --name db2server --restart=always --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=**** -e LICENSE=accept -e BLU=false -e ENABLE_ORACLE_COMPATIBILITY=false -e TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=true -e UPDATEAVAIL=NO -v "/home/tang/.config/ibm-db2-developerc/DB2/db2fs:/db2fs" db2server:v11.1.2fp2_2
[2017-09-07 12:19:09:0627] [info] inside runImage command: docker run -h db2server_e247e0 --name db2server --restart=always --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=**** -e LICENSE=accept -e BLU=false -e ENABLE_ORACLE_COMPATIBILITY=false -e TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=true -e UPDATEAVAIL=NO -v "/home/tang/.config/ibm-db2-developerc/DB2/db2fs:/db2fs" db2server:v11.1.2fp2_2


[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0444] [info] Starting DSM...
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0444] [info] dsm:v2.1.4_2
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0444] [info] runDockerImage: DOMAIN_INFO -> we.cumulusrepo.com/db2dg
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0445] [info] image: dsm:v2.1.4_2,  containerName: dsm
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0445] [info] before calling runContainer: dsm:v2.1.4_2, dsm
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0460] [info] runDatastudioImage - the datastudioName is equal to undefined
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0480] [info] command: docker ps --filter "status=running" error: null stdout: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
 stderr:
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0511] [info] command: docker ps --filter "status=exited" error: null stdout: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
 stderr:
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0544] [info] command: docker ps --filter "status=created" error: null stdout: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
 stderr:
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0544] [info] Getting DSM command to run for dsm:v2.1.4_2 and dsm
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0544] [info] Inside getDsmCommand ...
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0618] [info] Generated DSM command is:
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0618] [info] docker run -h dsm_c61b67 --name dsm --restart=always -p 11080:11080 -p 11081:11081 -p 11082:11082 -e DSM_ADMIN=dsmadmin -e DSM_ADMIN_PWD=**** -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=**** -e TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=true --volumes-from db2server dsm:v2.1.4_2
[2017-09-07 12:19:14:0619] [info] inside runImage command: docker run -h dsm_c61b67 --name dsm --restart=always -p 11080:11080 -p 11081:11081 -p 11082:11082 -e DSM_ADMIN=dsmadmin -e DSM_ADMIN_PWD=**** -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=**** -e TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=true --volumes-from db2server dsm:v2.1.4_2

[2017-09-07 12:19:31:0653] [info] command: docker run -h dsm_c61b67 --name dsm --restart=always -p 11080:11080 -p 11081:11081 -p 11082:11082 -e DSM_ADMIN=dsmadmin -e DSM_ADMIN_PWD=dsmadmin+10 -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=f1nalM0nth -e TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=true --volumes-from db2server dsm:v2.1.4_2 error: "

{ Error: Command failed: docker run -h dsm_c61b67 --name dsm --restart=always -p 11080:11080 -p 11081:11081 -p 11082:11082 -e DSM_ADMIN=dsmadmin -e DSM_ADMIN_PWD=dsmadmin+10 -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=f1nalM0nth -e TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=true --volumes-from db2server dsm:v2.1.4_2\n
docker: Error response from daemon: No such container: db2server.\nSee 'docker run --help'.\n\n    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:217:12)\n    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)\n    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)\n    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)\n    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:510:12)\n  killed: false,\n  code: 125,\n  signal: null,\n  cmd: 'docker run -h dsm_c61b67 --name dsm --restart=always -p 11080:11080 -p 11081:11081 -p 11082:11082 -e DSM_ADMIN=dsmadmin -e DSM_ADMIN_PWD=dsmadmin+10 -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=f1nalM0nth -e TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=true --volumes-from db2server dsm:v2.1.4_2' }" 

stdout:  stderr: docker: Error response from daemon: No such container: db2server.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Same-ish problem, but with the Mac version.

Docker version 17.10.0-ce, build f4ffd25

For the mac, it hangs on "Preparing to Download", with 0% displayed.  It downloads six files:

`datastudio.tar
 datastudio.tar.gz
 db2server.tar
 db2server.tar.gz
 dsm.tar
 dsm.tar.gz`

I'm guessing there's something borked in their electron installer so it doesn't update those percentages and just hangs without telling you why.

If Ubuntu works like Mac, look in the downloads folder and see if you have those folders.  You can then use `docker import dsm.tar` and such to run them.

How to finish from there, I'm not sure.  I don't know what the installers do after that, but a related post has this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062423/blank-screen-installing-db2-developer-community-edition-on-linux

```
a6897b6ff68f        dsm:v2.1.4_2             "/opt/start_dsm.sh"      16 hours ago        Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:11080-11082->11080-11082/tcp   dsm
3085e6a8bb4b        db2server:v11.1.2fp2_2   "/var/db2_setup/lib/e"   16 hours ago        Up About an hour    22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp       db2server
```

You might be able to use that and debug what's going on in your app.